# WSL2 Ubuntu time using wrong TZ to calculate locatime?

Tags: ubuntu, time-zone, wsl2

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 WSL2 machine running in Windows 10 and from time to time I get this weird problem where the time is out of sync in the WSL2 machine. My timezone is Eastern Time (-5) and as you can see below my WSL is 5 hours in the future. Feels like for some reason my WSL machine interprets my local time as UTC and do a calculation based on that information.

WSL2

```
$ date 
Fri Jan 22 03:13:28 EST 2021
$ cat /etc/timezone
America/Toronto
$ date +"%Z %z"
EST -0500
```

PowerShell

```
> date
Thursday, January 21, 2021 10:13:31 PM
> Get-TimeZone


Id                         : Eastern Standard Time
DisplayName                : (UTC-05:00) Est (É.-U. et Canada)
StandardName               : Est
DaylightName               : Est (heure d’été)
BaseUtcOffset              : -05:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : True
```

I tried doing a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` but it did not help.

EDIT: adding a screenshot, time won't match the time I mentioned before but the screenshot shows the correct local time and timezone.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a Ubuntu 18.04 WSL2 machine running in Windows 10 and from time to time I get this weird problem where the time is out of sync in the WSL2 machine. My timezone is Eastern Time (-5) and as you can see below my WSL is 5 hours in the future. Feels like for some reason my WSL machine interprets my local time as UTC and do a calculation based on that information.

This is a known issue with WSL2: [system date is not same with windows (WSL 2)
#4245](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245)

You have to run the following command within the WSL2 instance:

```
sudo hwclock -s
```

You could instead run the following PowerShell command:

```
wsl -u root sh -C "hwclock -S"
```

You also have to perform the following PowerShell command:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

You will have to restart WSL instance after you run that command.

The solution also requires Chrony to be used with the following option commented out within `/etc/chrony/chrony.conf`

```
# Stop bad estimates upsetting machine clock.
# maxupdateskew 100.0
```

If you are not already using it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y chrony && sudo chronyd
```

An alternative solution is adding the following to .bashrc:

```
# WSL2 clock skew hack
__customprompt() {
  NOW=$(date +%s)
  if (( NOW > WSL_NEXT_CLOCKSYNC )); then
    echo "$(date -Iseconds) - hwclock [$WSL_NEXT_CLOCKSYNC : $NOW]" >> ~/.wsltimesync
    nohup wsl.exe -u root -c 'hwclock -s' &>/dev/null &
    export WSL_NEXT_CLOCKSYNC=$(date --date='+5 minutes' +%s)
  fi
}
```

Source:

- [WSL2 clock skew hack](https://gist.github.com/noelbundick/53650f4d69559c21a4f95075d201098a)
- [WSL2 clock skew hack](https://twitter.com/acanthamoeba/status/1253094110266712064?s=09)

Another alternative solution is to handle it automatically within Windows based on the detection of a specific event that is logged.

This can be handled by the following PowerShell script:

```
function Log($message) {
    $output = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("u") + "`t$message"
    Add-Content -Path "~/.wsl-clock.log" -Value $output
}

Log "********************************"
Log "*** Update WSL clock starting..."

$runningDistroCount = wsl --list --running --quiet |
        Where-Object {$_ -ne ""} |
        Measure-Object |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

if ($runningDistroCount -eq 0){
    Log "No Distros - quitting"
    exit 0
}

$originalDate=wsl sh -c "date -Iseconds"

Log "Performing reset..."
$result = wsl -u root sh -c "hwclock -s" 2>&1
$success = $?
if (-not $success){
    Log "reset failed:"
    Log $result
    exit 2
} else {
    $newDate=wsl bash -c "date -Iseconds"
    Log "clock reset"
    Log "OriginalDate:$originalDate"
    Log "NewDate:     $newDate"
    exit 0
}
```

Source: [Fixing Clock Skew with WSL 2](https://stuartleeks.com/posts/fixing-clock-skew-with-wsl-2/)

You can also use [wsl-clock](https://github.com/stuartleeks/wsl-clock)

Additional Resources:

- [Time not synced in WSL2 - causing TLS issues #4149](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4149)
- [WSL2 date incorrect after waking from sleep #5324](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5324)
- [Time Synchronization](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp)
- [Homestead ought to enable host->guest clock synchronization on Hyper-V #1300](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1300)

Answer (score 0):

I just issued the following command:

`sudo hwclock -s`

and it worked for me. This command fixed the issue as described [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/error-failed-to-parse-session-token-jwt-expired/td-p/1423400).

The environment that I was using was:

- Operating System : Windows 10
- WSL running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS